# Limiting network logins to local subnet windows server 2008 r2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, local-area-network

I have an internet facing Windows Server 2008 R2 install. Lets say it's on 70.0.0.74. On 70.0.0.73 is our NAT/firewall that hands out IP addresses from 192.168.1.XXX.

I want to be configure the following:

1) I am able to authenticate and connect to network shares on the the server through the NAT/firewall (I can do this now.)
2) I want to prevent network authentication, connecting to network shares, from outside the server's subnet.

How would I go about configuring this from a network/security standpoint?

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent login via RDP, or you want to prevent connections to file shares, or maybe something else?

Comment: Prevent connections (or connection attempts) to network shares. Let me update the question.